# How can I detect the changes of repeating data using fortran or python?

Tags: python, search, fortran, detect, data-analysis

I have a file, which have repetitive format for every 302th line. Current file have 20000 frame.

```
      300
        1
      1    6    5    5    1
      2    6    4    6    1
      3    6    4    6    1
....
    298    8    1    9   87
    299    2    1    9   88
    300    8    1    9   88
      300 (same frame repeats from here)
        1
      1    6    5    5    1
      2    6    4    6    1
..
```

- First line contains number of data
- Second line means the frame number.
- 3th ~ 302th line have the data.

  - first column contains line index
  - 2nd~5th columns have data of interest.

I hope to do following analysis (I googled and they call it time-series analysis)

1. Collect every 81th (or nth line as input of user choice) line from each frame. I have 20k frame of data, so the collected data should contain 20k line for 81th line of all frame.
2. Check that collected data, if any change happens in 3th column or 4th column numbers, record that line with corresponding frame number. Print out result file with first column as frame number, and following columns as original 5 column data.

For example, if the data becomes

```
300
 12
...
 81    6    5    5    1
...
300
 13
...
 81    6    6    4    1
... 
300
189
...
 81    6    5    3    1
...
300
190
...
 81    6    4    3    1
...
```

Then the result output file hope to be such as

```
....
12    81    6    5    5    1
13    81    6    6    4    1
....
189   81    6    5    3    1
190   81    6    4    3    1
....
```

I really have no idea how can I write this kind of 'search/detect and record' process coding. Need any help in fortran or python please. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt to solve this problem in fortran or python?

Comment: We're here to help you with your code, not working for you :) That's why it's free

Comment: You __do__ have an idea how to do this, I just showed you how to produce this file in your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255291/python-read-and-write-the-file-of-complex-and-reapeating-format/20256110?noredirect=1)! You can use the same approach here.

Comment: @fscore I just gathered all '81th' line data from all frame, (step 1) which is not that difficult. But for step 2, I really couldn't think of any good way of loops. I'm quite elementary at such data analysis, the only thing I can do is just use for and if loops....

Comment: @aIKid I know, but 2nd step of that progress is too wall to me. I'm searching for any clues that I can get... Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SteinarLima Thanks. I didn't even know such modules exists. Let me dig in more with that module. Thanks again.